# Sqlite with PHP Select Query

Tags: php, sqlite, select

I am trying to query a sqlite and I cant seem to figure out why my query returns nothing...Please let me know what I am doing incorrectly:
Here is my code:

```
<?php

class MyDB extends SQLite3
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->open('zap.db');
    }
}

$dbname = new MyDB();
$tablename = "test";   

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 

$result = "select user FROM test";
echo "here";

$row = $dbname->query($result);

foreach ($dbname->query("$result") as $row) {
        print $row["user"] . "\n";
    }
```

?>

Comment: You're not using [PDO](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). You're using the [SQLite3 extension](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite3.php).

Answer (score 6):

[`SQLite3::query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.query.php) returns a [result resource object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.sqlite3result.php). You need to use the [`fetchArray`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3result.fetcharray.php) method on it to get rows from it:

```
$query = "select user FROM test";
echo "here";

$result = $dbname->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetchArray()) {
    print $row["user"] . "\n";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't use PDO :(

Comment: Neither does the question, see my comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class MyDB extends SQLite3
    {
        function __construct($db_name)
        {
            $this->open($db_name.".db");
        }

    }

$db = new MyDB($user_db);

$result = $db->query("your query ");
```

its working great with me in php...
you must be enable **SQLite3 module version** and **SQLite Library** in your phpinfo file...